# How does stack find packages from extra-deps?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#extra-deps

The docs mentioned one example of adding and extra-deps only by name. I know that we can specific GitHub url too, but when we provide just the name, how stack knows where to find a package that is not in the snapshot?

Comment: It will search on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/).

Comment: @sjakobi you could add some source and post it as an answer

Comment: There's a bit more info at https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/#hackage and about Hackage's package index at https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2018/07/pantry-part-1-package-index/.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the blog post mentioned by @sjakobi says that both cabal-install and stack uses the package index from hackage.